# GNU parallel not spawning new jobs

Tags: gnu-parallel

I've been using GNU parallel (20120422) to run ~4000 commands (inside the commands.list file) like:

```
cat commands.list | parallel --keep-order --max-procs 40
```

It all started ok, with 40 jobs runnning, but afer a while it only had 5 jobs running (some jobs take way longer than others). I waited for a couple of hours and at some point one of those 5 jobs finished and all of the sudden more jobs were spawned.

Is this behaviour intended? I would expect that it would always try to have ~40 jobs running, no? Is there some buffer limit for the --keep-order option that prevents more jobs to be launched?

thanks,

Comment: Yes there is a file handle limit for the --keep-order. If you are hitting it, you will get: 

parallel: Warning: No more file handles. 
parallel: Warning: Raising ulimit -n or /etc/security/limits.conf may help.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the intended behaviour. Please submit a bug report as per: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#REPORTING-BUGS